# I need to understand behaviour of enum in java example?

Tags: java, enums

The first one is enum class

```
enum coffeeSize{
    BIG(8), HUGE(10), OVERWHELMING(16);
    private int ounces;
    coffeeSize(int ounces ){
        this.ounces = ounces;
    }
    public int getOunces(){
        return ounces;
    }

}
```

This is class CoffeeTest1 and main

```
 public class CoffeeTest1 {
      coffeeSize size;

      public static void main (String args[]) {
          CoffeeTest1 drink1 = new CoffeeTest1();
          drink1.size = coffeeSize.BIG;

          System.out.println(" " + drink1.size.getOunces());
      }
}
```

The below is output

```
8
```

My question : 
   I don't understand the how `drink1.size.getounces()` manage to output 8. I haven't given constructor `coffeeSize(8)` object (ex: `coffeeSize somex = new coffeeSize(BIG)`). I want to know this simple subtle logic behind. Can someone help me understand please?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: Enum are classes with singleton instances of the inner objects. Based in that info, if you don't provide a constructor, the compiler provides the default (and in case of Enums, private) constructor, the enums can have attributes and methods also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***I dont understand the how "drink1.size.getounces() " manage to output 8.***
>
> [...]
>
> ***I want to know this simple subtle logic behind.***

To understand the logic behind this, you can think of your `enum` as a regular `class` (which is actually how it is compiled), and

```
BIG(8)
```

as an instance of this class similar to

```
new coffeesize(8);
```

It should now be clear why `drink1.size.getOunces()` prints 8: `BIG` is just an instance of the `coffeesize` enum, for which you set `ounces` to 8 when constructing it.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion: find, learn, and follow the Sun Java coding standards.   It'll improve your code's readability.

It outputs 8 because that's the size, in ounces, for BIG coffee size, according to your enum.  That's the value that you passed into the BIG constructor.

`drink1` is the instance of the class, which has a package visible data member of type `coffeeSize` named `size`.  Every `coffeeSize` instance has a method `getOunces` that returns the integer value that you passed into its constructor.

There's nothing subtle about it.

Comment: To clarify, when you create an enum, the enum calls it's constructor if available, and you see that it sets the ounces to 8.

Comment: Not an enum; this enum that you provided.  In most cases there's no need for all that extra machinery.

Answer (score 0):

You will notice the `getOunces` method is defined on the enum.  Enum values can themselves have properties and methods, in Java.

It is implied that `CoffeeTest1` has a field that references the enum value.

So `drink1` is an instance of that class..
the `size` property is set to the `BIG` instance of the enum..
`Big` has `ounces` 8.

Answer (score 0):

When you specifies `BIG(8)` you are creating it passing 8 to its constructor (10 or 16). When you use it `coffeeSize.BIG.getOunces()` you are invoking its method `getOunces`. `BIG`, `HUGE` and `OVERWHELMING` are the possible values for a `coffeeSize`, each one with its own state.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum Colour {
   Black,White,Red,Green,Yellow,Grey
}

public class EnumExample {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

     Colour colour;

     colour = Colour.Black;

     System.out.println("Selected "+colour+" Colour");

     colour = Colour.Yellow;

     System.out.println("Selected "+colour+" Colour");
  }

}
```

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as spam. Take a look at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: Avoid overt self-promotion. You might also be interested in [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/advertising)